# clearTimeout() not working in my scroll function

Tags: javascript, cleartimeout

I am trying to clear a setTimeout while scrolling up but am having a time trying to get it to work.

This is my code currently:

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0,
  scrollingDown = false,
  pageYOffset = 0,
  timer;

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction, false);

function scrollFunction () {
  pageYOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  // Scrolling down.
  if (pageYOffset > lastScrollPosition) {
    scrollingDown = true;
  }

  // Scrolling up.
  if (pageYOffset < lastScrollPosition) {
    scrollingDown = false;
  }

  if (scrollingDown) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      el.classList.remove("class");
    }, 800);
  }
  else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    el.classList.add("class");
  }

  lastScrollPosition = pageYOffset;
}
```

The classes add/remove correctly, and the `setTimeout()` is firing, but the `clearTimeout()` is not clearing the timeout.

I've tried resetting the `timer` in the else to `null`, and I've tried running the `clearTimeout()` in the "// Scrolling up." statement, both without success.

How would I get this clearTimeout() to work?

---

**Edits from comments:**

Adding a check for timer and resetting it to null on scroll up looks to work.

Updated code:

```
if (scrollingDown) {
  if (timer === null) {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      el.classList.remove("class");
    }, 800);
  }
}
else {
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = null;
  el.classList.add("class");
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens when this function fires twice with `scrollingDown === true`.

Comment: You should check whether the timeout function is already running. If you want to reset the timeout, cancel the old one and start a new one. If you want to keep the old timer, skip starting a new one.

Comment: Thank you! Both comments pointed me in the right direction.